# How to get year-month costs summary for certain category in DetailView, Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a table with expenses categories and when I click on the certain category it redirects me to this DetailView page. Then I want to show the year-month costs summary for chosen category to look similiar to this what I already got (summary per year-month but not for certain category). How can I achieve that?

This is what I got for now and got stucked:

```
def category_summary():
    summary_by_year_month = Expense.objects.annotate(
    month=TruncMonth('date')).values('date').annotate(
    amount=Sum('amount')).order_by()

return summary_by_year_month
```

MODELS.PY

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class Expense(models.Model):
    class Meta:
         ordering = ('date', '-pk')

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.date} {self.name} {self.amount}'
```

The most confusing part about this problem for me is how can I retrieve this information only for chosen category and show it to user in DetailView? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Why can't you just `filter` by the selected category before doing the annotations?

Comment: Because I don't know how to. I tried filtering, did bunch of stuff and this is all I could manage to do. Im a newbie do Django, it's been just 2 weeks since i started to learn it. Also I would appreciate if you were more specific, give some sample code or something, thanks.

Comment: Filters are kind of critical to using Django ORM well :) I suggest you read the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/. ALso see the Django Girls tutorial on the matter: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_orm/ - the whole tutorial is to be recommended.

Comment: But am I going to be able to make it work automaticly? I mean, when I will click e.g "sport" category in table then, I will see only year-month costs only for this in DetailView, right?

Comment: If you put it in your context for the view, then use that data in the form/template, then yes. Based on the questions you're asking, I strongly recommend you run through the whole Django Girls tutorial ... I promise you'll find it very helpful!

Comment: Thank you so much for help and leading me! :) Also, maybe you have some additional tips and advices for me? I would kindly appreciate :)

Comment: I think my biggest tip for a beginner is to run through a decent tutorial so you understand how Django hangs together, and the one I mentioned is one of the better tutorials. Plus, it's free :) Make sure you understand the Model/View/Template process and how they interact, and what Forms and Views do. If you can grasp all of that it will get you a long way.